# Displaying OWL file in web page

Tags: web, owl

Currently, I'm developing an ontology related to diseases using the software Protege. When I save the file, it's saved in OWL file displaying in XML. Now, I would like to know the method to call the OWL file in my website. I am interested to do a website which allows user to ask questions related to diseases and the answer comes from the ontology that I've created. Is there anybody who can enlighten me regarding this matter?

Comment: What programming languages and technologies do you use to develop your website?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you're looking for a tool that will let your users query your ontology.  SPARQL is an RDF query language that can achieve what you desire but I cannot recommend any of the available [SPARQL query builders](http://www.google.com/search?q=sparql+query+builder) as I have no experience with them.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing something similar -- right now I am looking at using java and OWLAPI -- (http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/index.html).

There is a PHP tool that I will look into as well -- (http://arc.semsol.org/).

You could always publish your ontology on freebase.com, and use their SPARQL endpoint.

A good place to get started on testing SPARQL out is http://dbpedia.org/snorql/